# web3.eth.accounts/web3.eth.getAccounts returns only the first account

Tags: blockchain, testrpc, ethereumjs

After initiating testrpc,

```
App.web3Provider = new web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545");  
web3 = new Web3(App.web3Provider);
```

it is displaying 10 accounts, but when accessing `web3.eth.accounts/web3.eth.getAccounts`, it returns only the first account. What went wrong?

Comment: `web3.eth.accounts[0]` thru `web3.eth.accounts[9]` should work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

try in this way and run for example with 'node file_name.js'

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3Provider = new 

Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545");
const web3 = new Web3(web3Provider);
const getAccount = async () => {
   const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
   console.log(accounts);
};
getAccount();
```

Answer (score -1):

you shoud use web3.eth.accounts instead, to get the list of all accounts.
Take a look at the documentation:
https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3eth

Comment: It displays on the account which that particular node controls not All accounts on the blockchain.